# Calling multiple react components from "index.html"

Tags: reactjs

I have an "index.html" file in my project and I want to call multiple react components from this index.html file.

Usually we call index.jsx from the index.html file using the getElementbyId in jsx file.
But here I need to call 2 different components in index.html itself.

index.html

```
   <div class="firstComponent"> </div>
   <div id="root" aria-live="polite"></div>
   <div class="secondComponent"> </div>
```

I want to call component firstComponent.jsx and secondComponent.jsx from the first and last divs.
Is there any way to implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done easily using multiple ReactDOM.render call for both the nodes.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import FirstComponent from 'path-of-your-firstComponent.jsx';
import SecondComponent from 'path-pf-your-secondComponent.jsx';

ReactDOM.render(
  <FirstComponent />,
  document.getElementsByClassName('firstComponent')[0]
);

ReactDOM.render(
  <SecondComponent />,
  document.getElementsByClassName('secondComponent')[0]
);
```